# One-dimensional initial value problem

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

Consider the initial value problem

> $$y'(t)=f\bigl(y(t)\bigr),\qquad   y(0)=a \in \mathbf R$$

where $f\colon \mathbf R \to \mathbf R$. 
Which of the following statements are necessarily true?
*a)* There exists a continuous function $f\colon \mathbf R \to \mathbf R$ and $a \in \mathbf R$ such that the above problem does not have a solution in any neighbourhood of $0$.
*b)* When $f$ is twice continuously differentiable, the maximal interval of existence for the above initial value problem is $\mathbf R$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming $\mathbf{R}=\mathbb{R}$:

a.) is false, by the standard existence and uniqueness theorems for first-order ODEs. See http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~tyson/existence.pdf.

b.) is true, and to see that it is, we achieve the maximum (note that $\mathbb{R}$ itself is the largest possible maximum in $\mathbb{R}$, so this is sufficient). Let $f(y(t))=0$, and we have the solution $y(t)=a$, which exists everywhere.

Comment: part b) is false.

Comment: It says "maximal" for a reason. Unless we're interpreting the question differently; my interpretation is, "There is an $f$ that is $C^2$ such that the interval of existence is $\mathbb{R}$." I believe your interpretation is, "For any $f$ that is $C^2$, the interval of existence is $\mathbb{R}$." Since, according to conventional definition, the maximum need not be achieved everywhere in $C^2$, I believe my interpretation is correct.

Comment: I would comment on your own answer, but I do not have sufficient reputation to do so.

Answer (score 2):

a) Is FALSE. This is a consequence of [Peano's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_existence_theorem).

b) Is FALSE. For example
$$
y'=y^2, \quad y(0)=1,
$$
then the unique solution is
$$
y(t)=\frac{1}{1-t}.
$$ 
Clearly, the solution is NOT globally defined, as it blows up at $t=1$, while $f=y^2$ is $C^\infty$.